# What is the proper SQLAlchemy ORM structure for a join table (1:multiple table relationship)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a join table such that:

```
Table A.b_id = Table B.id
AND
Table A.c_id = Table C.id
```

This way I safe space by creating an intermediary "join" table to define the relationship between B and C.

Is the proper way to define this below? I've been looking through the docs but they only define 1:many and many:1 relationships with examples - I don't see any situations such as the one I'm describing. Thanks in advance!

```py
class B(Base):

    __tablename__ = "b"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class C(Base):

    __tablename__ = "c"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class A(Base):

    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("b.id"))
    b = relationship("B")
    c_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("c.id"))
    c = relationship("C")
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone who's looking in the future. I was able to figure this out by reading the documentation (who woulda guessed?). The proper way to do this is as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer,
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class B(Base):

    __tablename__ = "b"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = relationship("A", back_populates("b"))


class C(Base):

    __tablename__ = "c"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = relationship("A", back_populates("c"))


class A(Base):

    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("b.id"))
    c_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("c.id"))

    b = relationship("B", foreign_keys=[b_id], back_populates("a"))
    c = relationship("C", foreign_keys=[c_id], back_populates("a"))
```